# Run a activity in a test and wait for button press from a physical user to continue?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a JUnit test for Android that loads an activity in a test, I need to load the Activity and wait for a button press to continue on through the test. I do not want the button press to be simulated it must be from a physical user. Is this possible in Android test?

Thanks

Comment: That's not a good approach. Lets imagine your test would be automatically run on a Continious-Integration server... There will be no possibility for the user to click the button in such cases.

Comment: @StefanBeike I know this is the case, It must run this way otherwise I would take a different approach.

Comment: Junit doesn't work that way. And if your test isn't going to be automated anyway why use an automated test framework? Just write a test script for a tester to follow.